# push_back struct into vector

Tags: c++, vector, push-back

```
 //prototype    
 void Split(char c, vector <MyString> &outputVector) const           

 //partial code inside split function
 // create new MyString object to push into output vector
 MyString substr;
 substr.mString = newString;
 substr.mLength = size;

 // push new item
 outputVector.push_back(substr);
```

After I step over the `outputVector.push_back()` line, the `mString` data member is not retained.

```
//I have two constructors
MyString()
{
    mString = NULL;
    mLength = 0;
}

/*************************************************
 * MyList copy constructor
 * creates a deep copy of a MyString item
 ************************************************/
MyString(const MyString &copy)
{
    mString = new char[copy.mLength];
    int i;

    for(; i < copy.mLength; i++)
    { mString[i] = copy.mString[i]; }

    mString[i] = '\0';
    mLength = copy.mLength;

}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Show us the definition of `MyString`

Comment: You *do* follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) for the `MyString` class? And is there a reason you don't use the standard `std::string` class?

Comment: @JhennaForonda Please don't post code or other crucial and important information as comments, edit your question to include it instead.

Comment: @Jhenna Foronda: Your code posted in comment were having lot of bugs. Can you repost the code?

Comment: In that copy-constructor, where do you initialize `i`? And does `mLength` include the string terminator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using an uninitialized variable which is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

```
int i;

for(; i < copy.mLength; i++)
```

Here we have no idea what `i` is so anything can be going on but most likely `i` is larger than `copy.mLength` so we never enter the for loop.  In order to get correct behavior set `i` to 0 like

```
int i = 0;
```

You have another issue with

```
mString[i] = '\0';
```

By the time we reach that line `i == copy.mLength` but the array only has the size of `copy.mLength` so we are one past the end since arrays are 0 index based.  Most likely you need to change your allocation to

```
mString = new char[copy.mLength + 1];
```

to give you space for the null terminator.

Comment: That totally fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/

push_back copies value to vector. Does MyString class have properly defined copy constructor, that copies mString member? I would guess this might be your problem.

Comment: An answer should not be a guess.  Now that the OP has actually provided code you can see they have a copy constructor but it has UB.

Comment: Sorry - posted answer before entire code was provided.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 2 mistakes ,you have done 
1.for(i; i < copy.mLength; i++)
    { mString[i] = copy.mString[i]; }
you have to mention ,where the loop will start .
2.mString = new char[copy.mLength + 1]; 
mString[i] = '\0';
i think ,you got the answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Correct version of copy constructor

```
MyString(const MyString &copy)
{
    mString = new char[copy.mLength + 1];
    int i = 0;

    for(; i < copy.mLength; i++)
    { mString[i] = copy.mString[i]; }

    mString[i] = '\0';
    mLength = copy.mLength;

}
```